# Matplotlib plot is plotting the wrong way

Tags: python, numpy, matplotlib

Using numpy and matplotlib, I'm trying to plot a polyfitted set of data points:

```
x = [0, 5, 10, 15, 20]
y = [0, 0.07, 0.14, 0.2, 0.27]
```

Using this code:

```
import numpy as np 
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt
x = [0, 5, 10, 15, 20]
y = [0, 0.07, 0.14, 0.2, 0.27]

poly = np.polyfit(x, y, 1)
f = np.poly1d(poly)

plt.plot(f)
plt.show()
```

The variable `f` in the above code is `0.0134 x + 0.002`. This polynomial, when plotted, is supposed to be leaning to the right. But when I plot it, it shows this:
[image: Plotted polyfit polynomial]

What could be wrong with the code?

Comment: What happens when you plot  y=f(x) versus x (instead of plotting f)

Answer (score 3):

What you see is the plot of coefficients of linear function `f`, but not its values. This is the same as plotting two points:

```py
plt.plot([0.0134, 0.002])
```

This happens because `f` is converted to list inside `plt.plot`:

```py
print(list(f))
```

```
[0.0134, 0.002]
```

The points are displayed with coordinates (0, 0.0134) and (1, 0.002), because 0 and 1 are default x-values in `plt.plot`.

What you want is to to evaluate `f` at points `x` and plot its values:

```py
plt.plot(x, [f(xi) for xi in x])
```

`[f(xi) for xi in x]` can be shortened just as `f(x)`, because f can take list arguments, so that the code becomes:

```py
plt.plot(x, f(x))
```

as already mentioned in other answers.

Because f is a linear function, just 2 points will be enough. x[0] is the first point and x[-1] is the last:

```py
plt.plot([x[0], x[-1]], [f(x[0]), f(x[-1])])
```

[image]

Answer (score 2):

You need to pass `x` values into the polynomial to get the corresponding `y` values:

```
plt.plot(x, f(x)) # this should solve your issue
```

Answer (score 1):

If you print out `f`, that returns `poly1d([0.0134, 0.002 ])`. So if you try to plot that, it will draw a line between 0.0134 and 0.002 on the [0, 1] interval.

What you really want to do is evaluate `f` at `x`:

```py
plt.plot(x, f(x))
```